# Enable Basic Authentication in Lucee (tomcat) with Apache

Tags: tomcat, authentication, coldfusion, lucee

I'm using apache with Lucee (tomcat). I have a dev site that I want behind basic authentication. I have apache configure and non ColdFusion pages require and prompt for authentication. When I navigate to a CF page basic authentication isn't being required.

What Tomcat / Lucee config file do I need to modify to either use the apache basic authentication on setup additional basic authentication?

I'm running Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Here's my site config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/dev/docroot

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/dev>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      AuthName "Secured Development Environment"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
      DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's what Lucee Added to my apache2.conf file

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfchart)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
    # optional mappings
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/flex2gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flex2gateway/$1
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/messagebroker/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/messagebroker/$1
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/flashservices/gateway(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flashservices/gateway$1
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/openamf/gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/openamf/gateway/$1
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/$1
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
</IfModule>
```

Here's my update config base on the recommendation

I updated my config based on your recommendation and it doesn't resolve the issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/dev/docroot

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/dev>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      AuthName "Secured Development Environment"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
      DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html
    </Directory>


  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfchart)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
  </IfModule>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't work and I'm not sure it is any different since the virtualhost are include before the IfModule

```
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Please add your Apache configuration for how requests to CF pages are sent to Tomcat and for the virtual host to the above. Without knowing what you have done it is impossible to say why it is not working, but it is not a Tomcat/Lucee issue, it will be related to how you have configured Apache.

Answer (score 1):

The requests are getting proxied off to Tomcat before they hit your VirtualHost. Move the `<IfModule>` stuff into the `<VirtualHost>` after the `<Directory>` definition. You will need to do this for each Virtual Host, so you might want to pop it into a separate file and then include in using the Include directive.

Also try adding in:

```
<Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    satisfy any
    deny from all
    require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Just after the `Require valid-user` line.

Comment: I updated my config based on your recommendation and it doesn't resolve the issue. I get prompted to log in, but when I hit cancel the request is still proxied to tomcat. - I'll post my update config in my question above.